# MySQL Connection and insertion with Ruby, need help in syntax issues

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm using RubyMine and I already have my db created. The main problem is I can't insert data into my DB.

Code and DB:

[image]

This is a code I'm working just to connect it to MySQL db

```
print "How much money did you earn today? $"
brut = Float(gets.chomp)
puts "This are your way to save your money:"
necesites = (brut.round(3) * 0.55)
play = (brut * 0.10)
education = (brut * 0.10)
ltsfs = (brut * 0.10)
give = (brut * 0.05)
ffa = (brut * 0.10)
puts "$#{necesites.round(2)} - Money for Necesites"
puts "$#{play.round(2)} - Money for Play"
puts "$#{education.round(2)} - Money for Education"
puts "$#{ltsfs.round(2)} - Money for Long Term Savings for Spending"
puts "$#{give.round(2)} - Money for Give"
puts "$#{ffa.round(2)} - Money for Financial Freedom Account"

require mysql    # if needed

@db_host  = "localhost"
@db_user  = "root"
@db_pass  = "toor"
@db_name = "SAVINGS"

client = mysql::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :username => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
@cdr_result = client.query("'INSERT INTO
  savings_db (NECE, PLAY, EDUC, LTSFS, GIVE, FFA)
  VALUES ('necesites', 'play', 'education', 'ltsfs', 'give', 'ffa')'")
mysql.close
sleep(10)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This one: :in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `mysql' for main:Object (NameError)
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You need quotes around mysql: `require "mysql"`

Comment: I made the change, same error came up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

17: `require "mysql"`

24: `client = Mysql.new(@db_host, @db_user, @db_pass, @db_name)`

Is `savings_db` the name of your table? If yes, than the SQL statement seems ok. (Nevertheless, I find `SAVINGS` for the database and `savings_db` for a table confusing).

Have a thorough look at this *MySQL Ruby tutorial*: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/

Comment: the DB name is SAVINGS and the table name is savings_db, I should created with inverted names uhh? jajajaja... noob here!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL begins with a capital.  All Ruby classes and modules by convention begin with a capital letter.

Excellent tutorial here:  http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/